# what is MyClass.class?

Tags: java

following is the code listed in MainClass.java.

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("main started...");

        Class c = MyClass.class ;
                        //this class variable seems to be public static.
                        //But, as it is clearly visible in the MyClass,
                        //no reference variable is declared.
                        //My problem is that from where this class variable
                        //came from.
                        //i also check out the Object.java file, but it also don't
                        //have any public static class variable of Class class
                        //like there is
                        //out (instance of PrintStream class) in System class.
                        //Hope all u mindoverflow guys help me to sort out
                        //this probz.

        try {
            Class.forName( c.getName() ) ;

            System.out.println("classloader of MyClass : " + MyClass.class.getClassLoader());

            System.out.println("classloader of MyClass : " + String.class.getClassLoader());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("main ended...");
    }
}

class MyClass{
    static{
        System.out.println("static block of MyClass class.");
    }
}
```

thnx coobird...
i found the article quite useful. :)

But, about litereals my knowledge is only limited to:

```
int i = 5 ;  //here 5 is an integer literal

float f = 5.6f ;  //here 5.6f is a float literal
```

the only non-primitive litereal, i know is

```
String str = "java" ;   //"java" is a String litereal
```

and class literal, which u and Jon Skeet make clear to me very well.

**are there more literals found in java???**

---

agreed...
so as per the discussion, total literals are categorized as:-

- primitive literals
- string literals
- class literal
- null

are there some more literals (to make the list a little longer **:)** )

---

***when i decompile the MainClass.class using decomipler, two Class
type static variables (may be coz, i have used class literal 2 times) are found to be automatically added, but never found to be used
in the code. Also, both the class literals are directly replaced from the class file where i have used them in the java file.***

**My code :-**

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("main started...");

        Class c = MyClass.class ;

        try {
            Class.forName( c.getName() ) ;

            System.out.println("classloader of MyClass : " + MyClass.class.getClassLoader());

            System.out.println("classloader of MyClass : " + String.class.getClassLoader());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("main ended...");
    }
}
```

**Decompiler generated code :-**

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class MainClass
{

    public MainClass()
    {
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("main started...");
        Class c = MyClass;
        try
        {
            Class.forName(c.getName());
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder("classloader of MyClass : ")).append(MyClass.getClassLoader()).toString());
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder("classloader of MyClass : ")).append(java/lang/String.getClassLoader()).toString());
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("main ended...");
    }

    static Class class$0;
    static Class class$1;
}
```

Comment: How about true and false, and character literals (char c = '\n')? See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10 for the complete list of literal types.

Comment: but the list don't have class literal, why so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's "class literal" - a simple way of getting the `Class<T>` for a particular type.

See [section 15.8.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2) of the Java Language Specification for more details.

Note that it's not a "field" of the class, it's a special piece of syntactic sugar.

Due to type erasure, you may run into interesting restrictions around generics. The [`TypeLiteral`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) introduced in Guice gives more information and a workaround.

In terms of implementation, it depends on which bytecode version you're targeting. If you use `-target 1.4` (or below), a call to `Class.forName()` is inserted into your code in a static method which is called during type initialization. If you use `-target 1.5` (or above) the constant pool gets a "class" entry. I don't know the details of how this is handled though.

Comment: No, System.out is just a normal field as far as the compiler is concerned. (It has some odd properties in other respects, but it's not treated differently by the *language*.)

Comment: Hijacking this, as I'm a C# developer a bit curious about Java: Is this roughly equivalent to typeof(Class) in .net?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, except C# supports generics rather better :)

Comment: r u sure? coz using MyClass.class don't executes the static block of MyClass, but using Class.forName("MyClass") does. i am executing code on jdk1.6

Comment: You're using JDK 1.6, so it's using a constant pool entry (as described in the answer) - this is slightly different to the pre-1.5 behaviour.

Comment: thts ok, but i don't know abt constant pool entry...
any reference link is highly appreciated....

Comment: See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ConstantPool.doc.html#67960

Comment: Class.forName(className) executes the static initializer code because it invokes Class.forName(className, true, loader), where the true part specifies the class will be initialized

Comment: thnx mr. skeet, the document is useful, but difficult to go through(but i am trying my best to get done with that).

Comment: where the two static Class variables are used (from reference to edited post).

Comment: The decompiler is showing odd results (invalid Java). Use "javap -c" to show the actual bytecode. Basically both references will refer to the same constant pool entry.

Answer (score 3):

Writing `MyClass.class` gives an object of the type `Class<MyClass>`.

So, in the above code, if one is to use generics correctly, it should rather say:

```
Class<MyClass> c = MyClass.class;
```

or

```
Class<?> c = MyClass.class;
```

The `class` keyword will give the `Class` object that models the class.

As mentioned by Jon Skeet, [Section 15.8.2: Class Literals](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.2) of [The Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) says the following about the class literal:

> A class literal is an expression
>   consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type,
>   or the pseudo-type void, followed by a
>   '.' and the token `class`. The type of a
>   class literal, `C.Class`, where `C` is the
>   name of a class, interface or array
>   type, is `Class<C>`.
>
> A class literal evaluates to the `Class` object for the named type (or for void) as defined
>   by the defining class loader of the class of the current instance.

Comment: Good point, probably the wording that it "returns" wasn't the best way to describe it. I've changed the wording.

Comment: What if the MyClass is a generic type,

class MyClass<E> {

} 

- How do I get the class MyClass<E>?

Answer (score 0):

To add to what others have already said, "MyClass.class" is semantically identical to:

```
Class.forName("MyClass", false, classloader);
```

where "classloader" is the ClassLoader instance of the calling class.

The main difference is in exception handling - with the above code fragment throws ClassNotFoundException, but I don't believe that MyClass.class can throw that (it may throw ClassDefNotFoundError, however, but that's a more general issue). Also, MyClass.class works with import statements, whereas Class.forname() requires you to pass in the fully-qualified class name.

---

As I was reminded, MyClass.class does not initialize MyClass, so the static initializer won't be called.

Comment: r u sure? coz using MyClass.class don't executes the static block of MyClass, but using Class.forName("MyClass") does. Then, how can the two be symantically identical.

Comment: Class.forName(className) executes the static initializer code because it invokes Class.forName(className, true, loader), where the true part specifies the class will be initialized

Comment: Just so. It's a non-obvious side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

Right, there's no "class" instance variable so to speak.  It exists in every class, actually.  MyClass.class gets the Class instance directly for MyClass.  I'm not sure how familiar you are with reflection, but this allows you start working with that.  You might check out this tutorial for some examples of what you can do:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-dyn0603/

Reflection allows programs to view and modify their own behavior at runtime.  Its a type of "metaprogramming."

Comment: i know reflection, but i don't know much about
details of class literal.